# Socket con bash

Tags: bash, socket

Estoy implementando sockets con Bash, pero no me lee nada.

Aquí está el código, si quito la redireccion al FD 3 sí que muestra el texto, pero es el propio netcat (no sale precedido de '> ', como tengo en el `echo`).

```
#!/bin/bash

host="localhost"
port="8000"

fd_file="fd_file"

# start FD 3
rm -f "$fd_file"
exec 3<> "$fd_file"

nc -k -l "$host" "$port" >&3 # init socket & resend it to FD 3

while read -u 3 a; do
    echo "> $a"
done

# close FD 3
exec 3<&-
rm -f "$fd_file"
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Al final he optado por usar `socat`.

Entonces, el código se simplifica muchísimo:

```
#!/bin/bash

while read a; do
    echo "($SOCAT_PEERADDR) $a"
done
```

Y para relacionar el .sh con la IP uso: `socat -u tcp-l:8000,pktinfo,fork exec:./ServersManagerConnector.sh`.

Comment: Y sin el `-u` todos los echos al FD 1 van hacia el cliente